# Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed in magento 2

Tags: magento2, cash-on-delivery

i have an issue in magento2-cash-on-delivery-fee extension. i have posted a issue in github kindly please verify in the below link.

https://github.com/bragento/magento2-cash-on-delivery-fee/issues/24

Comment: I have tested this extension in my setup and it is working fine...Can you please explain how to reproduce this issue?

Comment: i was recover that issue  by comment the setIsSkipValidation()  function after that extension works  fine. thank you @Ranganathan

Comment: Ok...Check you profile..India flag is disappeared https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/72237/divya-sekar

Comment: thank you. i will make reappear  the flag.